# What should the template be for regional/country code tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, country-tags, tag-wiki

Looking at tag wikis, what should the regional or country tags be?

Here are the region/country tags from the first page of tags:

- https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states
- https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada
- https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ontario
- https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom

The text I am discussing is what shows up in the box at the top.

Comment: FYI I updated the regions that show up on the front page of tags to match this standard.  United States, Canada, Ontario (thank you HST questions), and the United Kingdom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

excerpt: for questions that relate to the laws, practices, and products of the <country name>.

description: for questions that relate to the laws, practices, and products of the <country name>. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_states)

So we'd have:

united-states excerpt: for questions that relate to the laws, practices, and products of the United States.

united-states description: for questions that relate to the laws, practices, and products of the United States. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_states)

canada excerpt: for questions that relate to the laws, practices, and products of Canada.

canada description: for questions that relate to the laws, practices, and products of Canada. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada)

etc. etc.

Comment: Updated from laws to laws, practices, and products based on feedback.   Also changed to CW so others can edit.

Comment: Updated with separate excerpts and descriptions because you can't have links in excerpts.